# Rails - Linking existing models in HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models like this

```
class Student
   has_and_belongs_to_many :classrooms
end

class Classrooms
   has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

I want to take a student and link him to a class that exists in the database,
whenever I try to do this

```
classroom = Classroom.find(id)
student = Student.find(id)
Student.classrooms.create(classroom: classroom)
```

I get an error like this:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: classroom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
classroom = Classroom.find(classroom_id)
student = Student.find(student_id)

classroom.students << student
```